# Does tf.transpose also change the memory (like np.ascontiguousarray)?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow

If I use `tf.transpose` does it also change the memory layout?

In numpy it is used the function `np.ascontiguousarray`.

I mean this would be important if I use cuda. Because it makes a difference if the memory layout is [N C H W] or [N H W C]. (N ... Nr of samples, H ... array height, W ... array width, C ... array depth, e.g. RGB)

How to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read carefully [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) you can find the answer:

> Numpy Compatibility
>
> In numpy transposes are memory-efficient constant time operations as they simply return a new view of the same data with adjusted strides.
>
> TensorFlow does not support strides, so transpose returns a new tensor with the items permuted.

Hence `tf.transpose` returns a new tensor with the desired shape (and therefore is inefficient), so yes, it changes the memory layout.

However, instead of using `tf.trasnpose` you could use [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) for changing the tensor shape without creating a new one