# Tensor product of specified dimension without transpose

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, transpose, tensor

Suppose I have a tensor `t1` of size `(a, b, c)` and another tensor `t2` of size `(c, d)`. Is there a way to multiply these and get a tensor `t3` of size `(a, d, b)` (not `(a, b, d)`) without using the `tf.transpose` operation?

Working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf  # version 2.1.0
t1 = tf.constant(tf.reshape(range(24), (2, 3, 4)))
t2 = tf.constant(tf.reshape(range(20), (4, 5)))
t3 = tf.transpose(tf.tensordot(t1, t2, axes=[[2], [0]]), [0, 2, 1])  # shape = (2, 5, 3)
```

What I want is to get `t3` from `t1` and `t2` without using `tf.transpose`, which is supposedly expensive ([link 1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15697), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949463/does-tf-transpose-also-change-the-memory-like-np-ascontiguousarray)).

I'm using Tensorflow 2.1.0 with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.constant(tf.reshape(range(24), (2, 3, 4)))
t2 = tf.constant(tf.reshape(range(20), (4, 5)))

t3 = tf.linalg.matmul(t2, t1, transpose_a=True, transpose_b=True)
```

This is an efficient way to perform matrix multiplications without actually computing and storing the transposes.